# (Java reference situation) Should iI do what findbugs tools tells me to?

Tags: java, performance

I ran Findbug tool on my project and it found 18 problems of the type:

**Storing reference to mutable object** -> **May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object**

So I have a class which the constructor accepts array of type Object and assigns it to a private class member variable. Here is an example:

```
public Class HtmlCellsProcessing extends HtmlTableProcessing
{
    private Object[] htmlCells;

    public HtmlCellsProcessing(Object[] htmlCells)
    {
        this.htmlCells = htmlCells;
    }
}
```

Here is a further explanation about the warning:

*This code stores a reference to an externally mutable object into the internal representation of the object.  If instances are accessed by untrusted code, and unchecked changes to the mutable object would compromise security or other important properties, you will need to do something different. Storing a copy of the object is better approach in many situations.*

The advice they give me is pretty obvious but what happens if the array's size is very big and if I copy its values into the member variable array the application is going to take twice more memory.

What should I do in such a scenario where I have large amount of data? Should I pass it as reference or always copy it?

Comment: It depends. If you copy it it will take twice the memory, `System.arraycopy` is very fast. If this is your own code it shouldn't matter too much. If this is a public API then you may have to think harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. You have multiple concerns, including space, time and correctness.

A defensive copy helps you guarantee that the list items will not change without the knowledge of the class holding the array. But it will take O(n) time and space.

For a very large array, you may find that the costs of a defensive copy in space and time are harmful to your application. If you control all the code with access to the array, it may be reasonable to guarantee correctness without a defensive copy, and suppress the FindBugs warning on that class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd duggest you to try using immutable list from guava library. See http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained

Answer (score 1):

If both encapsulation and performance are required, the typical solution is to pass a reference to an immutable object instead.

Therefore, rather than pass a huge array directly, encapsulate it in an object that does not permit the array's modification:

```
final class ArraySnapshot {
    final Object[] array;

    ArraySnapshot(Object[] array) {
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array);
    }

    // methods to read from the array
}
```

This object can now be passed around cheaply, but the since it is immutable, encapsulation is ensured.

This idea, of course, if nothing new: it's what `String` does for `char[]`.

Comment: Note that this guarantee of immutability comes at a cost: having two copies of the array in memory at the same time, at least temporarily, and making an O(n) copy.

Comment: Copying the array (once) is likely less expensive that initializing it, so doesn't affect overall execution time that much (unlike defensive copying, this needs to be done only once, not the every time the object is passed around).

Comment: But of course, as you put it, "it depends". That's why this answer starts with "if encapsuation and performance are required". If encapsulation is not required, one can of course pass the reference to the array :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The advice they give me is pretty obvious but what happens if the
>   array's size is very big and if i copy its values into the member
>   variable array the application is going to take twice more memory.

In Java you *copy references not object themselves* unless you do a deep copy.
So if your only concern is to get rid of the warning (which is valid though especially if you don't understand what you actually store and you have multiple threads modifying the objects) you could do a copy without some much concerns on memory.

Comment: The question asks "what happens if the array's size is very big". Copying a "very-big" array may indeed require concern about memory.

Comment: You have a point there.But still the size is size of references.I think this distiction should be made since we don't really know what is "very-big" for the OP